# How manually create first request for asp.net mvc on iis7.5 when every time restart or release the website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

You guys all know: on **IIS7.5** the first request very **slow**. So I think maybe I can **manually create a request** when every time the website start, restart, after cycle time finish.....so on.

I'm search a lot , then I found Auto starting feature:http://www.schwammysays.net/auto-starting-websites-on-iis-7-5/

after I add this, I manually create a request in **Application_Start()** on **Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     ''    original logic here     ''

 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // send request after 100 second
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 100 * 1);
                    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                    using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InitialPath"]))
                    {
                        if (stream.CanRead)
                        {
                            log.Debug("warm success");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            log.Debug("can't read");
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex);
                }
            }));
}
```

but problem is :
1. that only fired when the IIS7.5 cycle time finish. not fired when restart website, start, or release it(even change web.config).
2. Some website still not fired, I don't understand.

So I'm searching Is there any other way can fired **Application_Start()** or create a request when website start, change, restart, IIS cycle time finish?
My server is : windows server 2008 r2

Answer (score 3):

The search term you are looking for is "application warm up".

You can use [Application Initialization Module for IIS 7.5](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization). Setup instructions can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/01/07/configure-the-iis-application-initialization-module.aspx). Note that you need to make some edits to the `applicationHost.config`, and you need to set it up specifically for your .NET framework version.

You can then have something like this in your `web.config`

```
<applicationInitialization
     doAppInitAfterRestart="true" >
   <add initializationPage="/" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

This will send a request to the root of your app (`initializationPage="/"`) every time your app starts automatically.

Answer found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/590865/how-can-i-warm-up-my-asp-net-mvc-webapp-after-an-app-pool-recycle/595215#595215).

Comment: my web.config file exactly like you suggest. but : 1.initializationPage not working, there is never a request access my website(I can see it on my access log). 2.it only firing``Application_Start()`` on ``global.asax`` when ``after an app pool recycle``. restart , start, change website not working.

Comment: I updated my answer. Apparently, you need to update the applicationHost.config file and do an IIS restart, and possibly a few other optional setup tasks.

Comment: I already edit applicationHost.config and put ``autoStart="true" startMode="AlwaysRunning" `` for app pool . and put ``preloadEnabled="true"`` for application.So now just like I said, it not send request to "/" when restart website. it only fired ``Application_Start()`` when IIS recycle.